# how to add new event in ical, in TERMINAL?

Tags: macos, bash, icalendar

how to use terminal to add event in ical without using other third party like icalbuddy??
someone had an idea in 2006, but it doesn't seem to work with leopard 10.6.7

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iCal" to make new event at end of calendar 1 with properties {start date:date "Sunday, March 5, 2006 1:02:00 PM", summary:"test event"}'
```

the above results in a bad syntax with the dates
Any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your local date format differs from one used in example, that's can be the reason of error.